# Wordpress : redirect url to a subdomain

Tags: wordpress, web, hosting

I have just hosted a wordpress website on godaddy .

I am having a situation .

I have a website   `www.example.com/cn`I want when someone open this page this page should redirect to  a sub domain  `cn.example.com`       .

I am hosting wordpress app first time kindly do let me know how can I do that .I am Python Guy I don't know about `htaccess`

I tried using `header('location:cn.example.com')`  in the `index.php`  file but the problem is `cn.example.com`  and `example.com/cn` both pointed to the same wordpress app .  So I am getting problem .

Please help me to figure out this problem .
**Updated Htaccess **

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/_dm/s/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|txt|ico|pdf|bmp|tif|mp3|wav|wma|asf|mp4|flv|mpg|avi|csv|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|zip|rar|tar|gz|dmg|iso)$ [NC]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.example.com/ [R,L]
##END MOBILE

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!cn.example.com)
RewriteRule ^cn/?$ http://cn.example.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks

Comment: If both domains are hosted on the same WordPress install, you will need to have multisite enabled before you can use different hostnames.

Comment: where I can enable this multisite in wp?

Comment: You can follow the guide [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) - without enabling it WordPress will redirect back to the value for `WP_HOME` for any different hostname. There may be some other alternatives by dynamically setting the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` to "trick" WorpPress into thinking the differing hostname matches. You can then do the rewrite using `mod_rewrite` in an `.htaccess` file in your root, or using the [WordPress Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are letting Wordpress load from the differing hostname, you can handle the rewrite by having the following in your `.htaccess` file found in the root of your Wordpress install:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!cn.example.com)
RewriteRule ^cn/?$ http://cn.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

It will match `/cn` or `/cn/` exactly from any host that is *not* already `cn.example.com` (prevent looping), and redirect to `http://cn.example.com` using a 301 HTTP response.

You can test these rules here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: What are you using at the input URL?

Comment: Yes while testing it is working but when I puted in htaccess it is not working I am updating my ht access please check

Comment: How is it not working? A 404 page? Redirecting to the home page? Do you see anything in the logs? Your rewrite should be *before* the WordPress rewrites - the `[L]` means it is the last rule processed.

Comment: I am getting not found but when I am opening cn.example.com  it works fine

Comment: Did you updated your .htaccess file? Your rewrite should go before the WordPress rewrite.

Comment: Yes I have puted on the top of wordpress you can check updated again .I am sorry for bothering you again and again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27306/discussion-between-masterofdestiny-and-doublesharp)